# Can I use multiple frameworks (Gantry & T3) on one Joomla installation?

Tags: joomla, frameworks, joomla3.0

so far we are only using rockettheme templates for our joomla 3. sites but I have found a very interesting shop theme (for virtuemart), which uses T3 and the developer couldn't tell me for sure if I will actually be able to use it on the current setup.

Can someone tell me if it is possible to use those two frameworks side by side (for different areas / menu items on a single side)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

There shouldn't be any issues using two frameworks.

You'll have to install each template and it's framework's plugin/extras and then apply each template to the section you want.

Let's say you use Gantry for the whole site and then T3 for the eCommerce part.

The Gantry template will call all it's neccesary js/css and so on when needed and won't be called when you are in the eCommerce parte.

I would suggest using just one (the most flexible for you/your developers) on the long run, to avoid a huge codebase just for a few different layouts, more things to update all the time, and so on.

Hope it helps :)

PS: I prefer T3

Comment: Thank you Fransisco, that was exactly the information I was looking for.

Usually we only used Gantry but we found few (=none) useful eCommerce templates for it so we will have to mix for now.